# Rapid web requests to many different websites using HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, http, httpclient

My team maintains a tool that is responsible for doing rapid verification of over 1000 different client websites.  The tool is a Windows Service (.NET 4.5.2, C#) that reads requests from a queue, and executes a 'health check' for each request.  It usually handles over 500 requests a minute, but can be responsible for more.  Each request takes a second or two to execute.

A request contains a `Uri` and credentials needed for doing the health check.  A health check is a `POST` against the AUTH page with the credentials (the app has custom auth, it's not header based auth), and then a `GET` to the home page, with a quick verification that it's the home page we expect.  It then goes to a status page in the application, and does some quick checks against that.  The GET requests have to use the cookies from the Set-Cookie header in the auth post.

We've been having performance problems with the tool as it scales.  It currently creates a new `HttpWebRequest` object for each post and get in the process.  There is a shared CookieContainer that is populated by the first post, so that we can get to the home page and then the status page.

I want to change this service to use the `HttpClient` object available in **.NET 4.5.**  The problem is everywhere I read online says you want to avoid rapid creation and destruction of `HttpClients`.  You'd rather keep one instance alive for the lifetime of the application.  The problem I have is that `HttpClient` seems to work really well against one endpoint, not many.

I have looked into several options, and am not sure which is best to proceed:

1. Create a new `HttpClient` for each request, and use it for the duration of that request.  That means it will live for a couple seconds, and be used for 3 calls.  This would not be easy to implement, but I'm concerned about the overhead of creating and destroying hundreds of `HttpClients` a minute.
2. Figure out if it's possible to use one `HttpClient` instance for different endpoints by avoiding usage of a `BaseAddres`s, and using the client to pass `HttpRequestMessages` using `SendAsync`.  <strike>I haven't been able to figure out cookies with this method yet.  To avoid having the `HttpClient` store the cookies, I set `UseCookies` to false in the `HttpClientHandler`, and tried managing cookies via headers in the `HttpRequest`/`ResponseMessages` themselves, but it looks like `HttpClient` simply strips cookies when `UseCookies` is set to `false`, so I was unable to pass cookies between request.</strike> edit: cookies work fine because they are stored per domain.
3. Store several hundred different `HttpClient` instances in some sort of dictionary, and pull the appropriate one for each `Uri` as the requests come in.  I'm not sure about the memory overhead on this though.  Also each unique `Uri` is only verified once every 5 minutes, so I'm not sure if having an `HttpClient` used once every 5 minutes keeps an unnecessary number of ports open.
4. Keep using `HttpWebRequests`.  Maybe this older method still performs better in this situation.

If anyone has faced a similar issue, I'd love some input on where to proceed on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to store the cookies? From the original description, it almost sounds like you WANT to reuse them "so that we can get to the home page and then the status page".

Comment: @Colin - We would be running parallel requests against dozens of sites at the same time.  Each of these sites is different instances of the same application, so all the cookie names are the same.  I'm not sure how one instance of HttpClient would handle that.  What if I auth against client A, then client B goes to GET the status page, will it use the cookies that client A just set in the shared CookieContainer?  That would cause some weirdness.

Comment: can you use one HttpClient per site?

Comment: That was suggestion number 3 I had there.  I could certainly try it, but I'm not sure how much overhead there is with having over a thousand HttpClient objects instantiated at the same time.

Comment: You shouldn't have to cache HttpClient connections as the .NET infrastructure uses a ConnectionPoint interface that caches server connections for you as long as your requests use KeepAlives. Take a look at ConnectionPointManager. Since you have many different sites you'll need to configure the CPM with lots of possible connections but even then I think caching might run into perf limits as you end up with too many ports open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with creating new HttpClients for each request is that HttpClientHandler will close the underlying TCP/IP connection.  However, if you are using each HttpClient for the 3 requests to one host and then hitting a different host, then keeping the connection open doesn't help when you move to a new host.  So, you probably will not see perf problem with one client per host.  HttpClient itself is a very lightweight object.  It isn't going to cost much to create one.

However, HttpClient simply delegates the real work to HttpClientHandler which uses HttpWebRequest under the covers, therefore will be unlikely to have any better performance than directly using HttpWebRequest.

If you are looking for better performance, then I suggest looking into replacing HttpClientHandler with the new [WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/4.0.0-beta-23516) which bypasses HttpWebRequest and goes directly to the Win32 API to make calls.

The full source is available for [WinHttpHandler on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler) so you can see exactly how it handles cookies and credentials.

And I would be really interested to hear if you do get much better perf with WinHttpHandler.

Comment: Thanks for commenting so quick!  Your comment rules out option number 2.  Would there be any advantage to option #3?  Each unique Uri only has tests run against it once every 5 minutes, so most of the time each Uri specific HttpClient instance would sit there doing nothing.  The only advantage there is we avoid spinning up a new HttpClient every 5 minutes for each Uri.

I'll also check out this WinHttpHandler, seems like something we could take advantage of.

Comment: @aalkema HttpClient doesn't actually manage cookies itself.  It delegates that job to the same CookieContainer used by HttpWebRequest.  There should be no problem avoiding the use of BaseAddress and using SendAsync instead.  GetAsync just tunnels to SendAsync under the covers.  The CookieContainer instance is held by the HttpClientHandler, so disposing the HttpClient will destroy the cookie container

Comment: @aalkema I'm not sure why you are having problems with cookies when you use SendAsync.  That should work just fine.  Cookies are associated to a domain so there should be no issue with cookies overlapping from one domain to another.

Comment: You're right - I whipped up a quick test app and the cookies are stored correctly by domain, so I could conceivably use one HttpClient for all requests, even though they are all different domains.  Is there going to be any advantage to that?  We run tests concurrently, but HttpClient is thread safe.  Under the hood is it going to be ok with concurrent connections to different endpoints?  Will we still see the performance advantages of HttpClient reusing TCP connections that we don't get right now by building HttpWebRequests ourselves for each request?

Comment: @aalkema Yes HttpClient will be fine with making multiple requests to different domains on different threads.  You should see the same perf you are getting with HttpWebRequests directly, unless you move to the WinHttpHandler.

Comment: @aalkema The only issue is how does CookieContainer scale.  One HttpClient will mean one CookieContainer.  If you are hitting 1000 websites, that will mean at least 1000 cookies in the container.  Not sure how well that data structure will scale.

Comment: MSDN documentation for CookieContainer capacity claims it will clean up expired or the oldest cookies in the container if it tries to add a new cookie while at capacity, which will probably work fine for us.  I think I'll try using one HttpClient for all requests, while using the WinHttpHandler under the hood.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: FWIW when using HttpWebRequest/HttpClient using 'cached' HTTP clients provides you no benefit as the ConnectionPointManager will do that for you automatically as long as keep alives are enabled on the request. Connections to a specific site are left open. Tweaking the number of connection points can help for high volume operations. But overall performance is still not quite that great. Also keep in mind if you're stress testing on Windows against an IIS server locally that IIS is limited to 10 connections so local testing will be limited to what IIS can do with 10 connections.

Comment: @RickStrahl  WinHttpHandler works fine on a regular desktop app as long as you are targeting .Net Framework 4.6

Answer (score 0):

To start with, what part of this would you need modified to suit your needs?

```
var urisToCheck = new List<Uri>(); //get these somehow

//basic auth work?
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

Parallel.ForEach(urisToCheck,
    async uri =>
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri.AbsoluteUri);
        //check for whatever you want here
    }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  The list of URIs should actually be a list of "Requests", and each request has a Uri, user and pass.  The problem here is more of the work should be in the Parallel Foreach - first you have to PostAsync against the Uri with the unique user/pass combo for that site, then do a GetAsync against the status page.

So the problem I have is how does HttpClient handle cookies with the same names, but different values for different Uris?  I imagine it only has one CookieCredential object, so this probably won't work.

Comment: @aalkema - do groups of requests re-use credentials, or does each request have its own credentials? I know you mentioned having several different servers, but is there one set of credentials per server at least?

Comment: each request has it's own credentials.  The Uri is for a web app - it logs in via a load balancer using those creds once every 5 minutes for each unique Uri.

Answer (score 0):

here's my basic API client that uses the same HttpClient object for every request.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//You need to install package Newtonsoft.Json > https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;


public class MyApiClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private HttpClientHandler _httpClientHandler;
    private readonly string _baseUrl;
    private const string ClientUserAgent = "my-api-client-v1";
    private const string MediaTypeJson = "application/json";

    public MyApiClient(string baseUrl, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        _baseUrl = NormalizeBaseUrl(baseUrl);
        _timeout = timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);   
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string url, object input)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var requestContent = new StringContent(ConvertToJsonString(input), Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeJson))
        {
            using (var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestContent))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(string url, object input) where TResult : class, new()
    {
        var strResponse = await PostAsync(url, input);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(strResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
    }

    public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string url) where TResult : class, new()
    {
        var strResponse = await GetAsync(url);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(strResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> PutAsync(string url, object input)
    {
        return await PutAsync(url, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input), Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeJson));
    }

    public async Task<string> PutAsync(string url, HttpContent content)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, content))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> DeleteAsync(string url)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var response = await _httpClient.DeleteAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClientHandler?.Dispose();
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
    }

    private void CreateHttpClient()
    {
        _httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
        };

        _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler, false)
        {
            Timeout = _timeout
        };

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(ClientUserAgent);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_baseUrl))
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);
        }

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MediaTypeJson));
    }

    private void EnsureHttpClientCreated()
    {
        if (_httpClient == null)
        {
            CreateHttpClient();
        }
    }

    private static string ConvertToJsonString(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
    }

    private static string NormalizeBaseUrl(string url)
    {
        return url.EndsWith("/") ? url : url + "/";
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
using ( var client = new MyApiClient("http://localhost:8080"))
{
    var response = client.GetAsync("api/users/findByUsername?username=alper").Result;
    var userResponse = client.GetAsync<MyUser>("api/users/findByUsername?username=alper").Result;
}
```

Register this object as singleton to your dependency injection library. It's safe to reuse because it's stateless.

**Do NOT recreate HTTPClient for each request**.

Reuse Httpclient as much as possible